# Uncaught ReferenceError: getTodayRequest is not defined(…)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have made a very simple list which with clicking on the first `li` tag show trigger a js function, but it complains with the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: getTodayRequest is not defined(…)
```

Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<script>
        function getTodayRequest(){
            console.log("here is today");
            alert("here is today");
        }

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div th:fragment="statistic_menu">
        <div class="panel">
             <div class="panel-body">
                 <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                   <h3 class="animated fadeInLeft">Statistic</h3>

                   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                       <li onclick="getTodayRequest()">Today</li>

                   </ul>
               </div>
             </div>                    
         </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: everything is correct... no error

Comment: @DineshSubhashPatil, why is jQuery needed?

Answer (score 0):

nothing is wrong it works fine

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<script>
        function getTodayRequest(){
            console.log("here is today");
            alert("here is today");
        }

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div th:fragment="statistic_menu">
        <div class="panel">
             <div class="panel-body">
                 <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                   <h3 class="animated fadeInLeft">Statistic</h3>

                   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                       <li onclick="getTodayRequest()">Today</li>

                   </ul>
               </div>
             </div>                    
         </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```